# jquery select menu not triggering correct alert

Tags: jquery

I am trying to trigger an alert, if the select menu chooses a specific option, but it is not firing the correct one. It may have something to do with the value, but I cannot pinpoint the issue.

```js
 $("#result3").on("change", "#txtArea1",function () {
    var theType = $("#txtArea1:selected").val();
    if (theType == "1") {
      alert("you selected Georgia");

    } else {
alert("you selected one of the 50 states");
        }
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result3">
<select name="txtArea1" id="txtArea1" size=10>
<option value="0"> Select a State</option>
<option value="1">Alabama</option> 
<option value="3">Alaska</option> 
<option value="4">Arizona</option> 
<option value="5">California</option> 
</select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

`var theType = $("#txtArea1:selected").val();`

with

`var theType = $("#txtArea1 option:selected").val();`

[UPDATED JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9k06g0bm/1/)

**UPDATE:**

The above change does not work in all browsers:

Try this:

`$('#txtArea1').find(":selected").val();`

Reference: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-get-the-text-value-of-a-selected-option/

Comment: @Phani You're misreading the reference link. The correct way is just `$("#txtArea1").val()`.